# Ionic Modal On Dismiss Bug

Tags: angular, angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic6

I was building a small app and I found this "bug" because I don't know if maybe it's something that has happened to more people but I think it's interesting to mention here. So the problem is that I've made a modal with a simple login form. When you submit the data from the form it enters the method `login()` as you can see in the code example below. The problem is that when the login method is called and all is done I dismiss the modal passing data in order to inform the other page that something has changed. But curiously this `modal.onDismiss()` passing data is not fired on the page when I'm on the web. It only fires when is a mobile and the modal is full screen. Does somebody know why this happens and how to solve it?

The method that opens the modal:

```
async showLoginModal() {
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: LoginModalComponent
});
await modal.present();
this.menuController.close();
modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  Storage.get({ key: 'user' }).then( response => {
    let user: User = JSON.parse(response.value);
    console.log(user);
    if(user.email != null){
      this.logged = true;
    }
  });
});
}
```

login method fired on submit inside the modal.

```
async login(){
let user: User = {
  email: this.credentials.controls['email'].value
}
await Storage.set({ key: 'user', value: JSON.stringify(user) });
await this.modalController.dismiss(user);
}
```

And here I leave a video to show you in a more visual way: [Click me](https://www.loom.com/share/4107386cee2845599276f02771c20b8e)

Comment: I'd recommend to fill a bug report here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code this way

```
async showLoginModal() {
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: LoginModalComponent
});
modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  Storage.get({ key: 'user' }).then( response => {
    let user: User = JSON.parse(response.value);
    console.log(user);
    if(user.email != null){
      this.logged = true;
    }
  });
});
await modal.present();
this.menuController.close();
}
```